# How to uninstall eziriz .NET reactor?

Tags: uninstall

Using `msiinv` [(see here)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer/), I have found that I have some leftovers of [eziriz's .NET reactor](http://www.eziriz.de/dotnet_reactor.htm) on my system although I had uninstalled it via Control Panel. It seems that those leftovers can't be uninstalled.

What I did:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>msiinv -s

[...]

.NET Reactor
        Product code:   {6732AE9F-CE1A-4DC7-A18D-A23CAA99724C}
        Product state:  (5) Installed.
        Assignment:     per machine
        Package code:   {2C38D41C-C21B-4AB0-BA31-E5EAF0B22577}
        Version:        4.6.0.0
        Publisher:      Eziriz
        Language:       1033
        Suggested installation location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Eziriz\.NET Reactor
        Installed from: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mia1\
            Package:    dotnet_reactor_setup.msi
        Instance type:  0
        Local package:  C:\Windows\Installer\149ce766.msi
        Install date:   2013\10\14
        15 features.
                0 features are not used.
                0 features are advertised.
                0 features are absent.
                15 features installed to run local.
                0 features installed to run from source.
                0 features installed for default.
                0 features in some other state.
        0 patch packages.

[...]

C:\Users\Administrator>msiexec /x "{6732AE9F-CE1A-4DC7-A18D-A23CAA99724C}"
```

The last command shown above runs without any error message. But .NET reactor is still installed afterwards.

I also have tried [Microsoft's Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed), using all of the few different options and methods it offered. But it couldn't fix the problem as well.

Any ideas of how to uninstall that software?

Comment: *Any ideas of how to uninstall that software?* - Manually find each component and delete it.

Comment: Actually, there is one than more problem of that sort. I just have picked .NET reactor to explain my problem, hoping somebody would give a general solution. Manually removing all affected programs would be a lot of work and (probably) quite error prone.

Comment: You are going to have to reduce the scope of your question if thats the case.  What an application's installer removes when its uninstalled is entirely up to the author of the installer (.msi)